# ember js binding delay

Tags: data-binding, ember.js

I need some help on some mixing I'm trying to do but I'm not sure about the best way to do it

so I'm trying to do some dealyed binding, or delayed observer, which I'd setup on a property, and a delay given in ms, and it'll update (in case of binding) or call (in case of observer) on change after some delay, but reseting this delay if in between the value of the property observed has changed again

help me!

Comment: can you show code where you want to do the observing delay?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for something like `debounce` function? http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_debounce